# How to verify a name using double entry?

Tags: string, loops, python-3.x, input, verification

I am creating a program in Python which asks the user to enter their name.
I am also trying to verify this by letting the user type it on twice and the program would only run if the user enters their name correctly twice.

Please have a look at the code below and please provide me with any suggestions

```
from random import randint 
name3 = 1

while name3 == -1:
    name = input("Please enter your name ")
    name1 = input("Please enter your name again for verification ")

    if name == name1 :
        print("you may now start the quiz")
    else:
        print (" The two names are different please enter you your name again")
        name3 = name3 + 1
```

Comment: you haven't told us what is the problem

Comment: The problem is it just skips ths whole code or says name is not defined.

Comment: the objective is that the user should enter their name twice. Only once they have entered their name correctly will the program run. Does that help?  Thanking you for help.

Comment: You start with `name3 = 1`, so the `while` loop never starts. Did you mean `name3 = -1`? Alternatively, just use `while True` and `break`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Could you please explain  further. I am justy a beginner and I am really interested in learning.

Comment: Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Then I suggest you have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a simple model to check the username and limit the number of retry

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name ")
name1 = raw_input("Please enter your name again for verification ")

retry_count = 0
while (name != name1):
    retry_count += 1

    print ("The two names are different please enter you your name again!")
    name = raw_input("Please enter your name ")
    name1 = raw_input("Please enter your name again for verification ")

    if (retry_count > 3 ):
        break
if (retry_count > 3):
    print("Too many retry!")
    # do something
else:
    print("you may now start the quiz")
```